# Word 365 character encoding annoying

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++, sublime-text-2, character-encoding, utf-8

When I open some text files with Microsoft Word 365 (v2001 build 12430.20184 - 16.0.12430.20172) it asks me to choose the characters encoding.

My question is: How to clean the original file to let Word opening this file without asking for the charenc ?

I mean, when you create a new test file with notepad (with 1 or 2 words inside) then save it with the same extension than my file then open it with Word, it does not ask for the charenc. It means that something is wrong with the original file.

How to "clean" it ?
With Notepad++ and Sublime Text 3, I tried to change the charenc to UTF-8 without BOM (the same as my test file), I tried to replace weird characters with the usual one but it still ask for the charenc...